# How to dockerize and deploy an Express backend and a React frontend app talking to each other using Websockets without CORS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, websocket

I have an Express app that acts as a WebSocket server and a React Vite frontend (NOT STATIC) that needs to be deployed to GCP or AWS. This is the folder structure of the apps

```
/my-app
  /frontend
    /Dockerfile
  /backend
    /Dockerfile
  docker-compose.yaml
```

I was able to create Docker images for each and containerize them using the docker-compose in the root folder. I tested the container locally and it works flawlessly. However, I am unable to find any help online on how I can deploy this.

From what I understood I have to push each docker image to a container registry and then deploy it on GCP or AWS.
The confusion I am facing is that I have two images or boxes in one container. Shouldn't I be pushing the container to the Container registry? Will it have any CORS issues? Because I have not done any env variables in the frontend or backend, just exposing the ports. I read somewhere that the host will be mapped to `0.0.0.0` as long as both the frontend and the backend are in the same network.

What is the best approach and practice to dockerize and deploy such an app? Do I need to use Kubernetes? The frontend is not a static site and not using the build version, it is run by `npm run dev` and connecting to the backend via Websockets. The backend maintains an open connection and emits messages back to the frontend as well.

Comment: I think your concern are not at the right place in your use case. In fact, if you have 2 containers that communicate each other in HTTP (websocket is HTTP), you can use Cloud Run on Google Cloud. About CORS, it's a preflight request sent by the browser. But if the websocket communication is initiated by a server, you haven't CORS issue, because there is no browser. The problem could come from the backend. Is it stateless? Is it always on? What is it's life cycle? Same for the frontend?

Comment: The app is a voting app, the frontend emits votes via the socket to the backend, that has a setup of websocket server with origin: 'http://localhost:5173', the backend gets the votes from vote page & emit back to the dashboard page. So this is working in locahost. However when i deploy the images to kubernetes GKE as frontend and backend services they cannot communicate each other. There is a state in the frontend, the votes are stored in the store and the dashboard gets the votes count from store, the dashboard also recieves votes from other clients connected to the server via the websocket.

Comment: There is no database as the values will be reset when the dashboard is refreshed.
I thought the whole point of having docker images is that if it works in your local it will work wherever it is deployed. clearly i am missing something. I know it has to be deployed as two separate services because the backend should be able to connect to multiple clients. How to do the setup of the WebSocket server instead of using 'localhost:5173'
 where should I deploy the images, eg in GCP should it be Cloud RUn or GKE or Compute Engine?

Comment: I still have question about the backend. Can it be shut down if there is no "dashboard" or "client to poll"? There is no issue to do websocket with cloud run. Expose bind the correct port when you deploy your backend, set the Cloud Run backend URL in your frontend (instead of localhost), and it should work fine. But..... I'm still quesitonning the websocket design for polling (HTTP REST request is enough for that) and for the dashboard (Long polling is also a viable solution.)

Comment: This is a test assignment project so I have not thought about shutting down the backend, I will terminate the project altogether in a few days. Long polling is not an option for the test, I need to get real-time updates of clicks happening, such are the requirements.
So according to your suggestion, I need to deploy both images to Cloud Run and provide the correct URLs for each end and it should work fine. right?
Forgive my naive questions, but how do i know what will be the deployment urls? Is there any way i can set up the env variables before hand?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up successfully deploying my container aka images in cloudrun. It was pretty straightforward. just needed to create production URL env variables in cloudrun and they worked perfectly.
To anyone who might find it useful,

1. push docker images to container registry
2. deploy them in cloudrun and copy the urls
3. re-edit the deployment and create new env variables, paste the production urls for process.env.PORT or whatever, and re deploy